# includegraphics stopped working after including another graphic

Tags: floats, errors, include

Currently using Texmaker and using this line of code:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{Figures/Blah}
\caption{\label{Blah} BLAH BLAH}
\end{figure}
```

Everything worked with several other figures until I tried to add a new figure. Now I get these error messages for every figure despite deleting the new figure I added.

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \begin{figure}[h!]
! Undefined control sequence.\@xfloat@LaTeX ...f \fi \global \setbox \@currbox\color@vbox \normalcolor \... \begin{figure}[h!]
! Missing number, treated as zero
```

---

```
\documentclass[aps, prl, twocolumn, floatfix, final, letterpaper, citeautoscript, superscriptaddress]{revtex4} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Comment: are you using the package `float` or `subfloat`?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \documentclass[aps, prl, twocolumn, floatfix, final, letterpaper, citeautoscript, superscriptaddress]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}

Comment: @StevenButton remove `subfigure` and add `float` and `subfloat`.  I believe `subfigure` will complain when used with `float`.  You can have `subfig` and `wrapfig` with then though.

Comment: No change when including float and subfloat

Comment: Well Fixed it. I apparently deleted an end{abstract}